# operator overload. q = q1+q2, q1 being modified but I want q1 and q2 to be intact

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, operator-overloading

I learnt operator overloading like 1 or 2 weeks ago and I think I know how it works but I'm trying to overload the operator `+` so it returns a new `CCuaternion` which is working well but

```
CCuaternion(float w, float x, float y, float z) {
    this->w = w;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->z = z;
} //Ccuaternion constructor at Ccuaternion.h

CCuaternion operator + (CCuaternion &q2); // at CCuaternion.h

CCuaternion CCuaternion::operator + (CCuaternion &q2){ // at Ccuaternion.cpp
CCuaternion suma;

suma.setW(w += q2.getW());
suma.setX(x += q2.getX());
suma.setY(y += q2.getY());
suma.setZ(z += q2.getZ());

return suma; }
```

In my `main` I have an object `CCuaternion` called `qsuma` which receives the `CCuaternion` that the overload is returning. It looks like this:

```
q1 = CCuaternion(0, 1, 0, 1); // at main.cpp
q2 = CCuaternion(1, 0, 0, 1);

qsuma = (q1+q2);
```

As supposed to, `qsuma` ends up with the values `1, 1, 0, 2`.
`q2` stays the same but `q1` ends up with the same value as `qsuma`.

Comment: Do you know what `+=` means?

Comment: yeah, now that you point that out... I feel kinda stupid. it should be just the +, right? as += is adding the value to w. 

I had the += because before I had the overload to change the value of q1 so I could do q1+q2; q1+q3; q1/q4; and so on but as I added more operations I needed the overload to function in a different way. 

thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You should take q2 by const reference.

Comment: FYI it's [Quaternion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) :)

Comment: yeah but it's Cuaternion is spanish :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are doing it the wrong way:

```
CCuaternion operator + (const CCuaternion& q2) const; // at CCuaternion.h

CCuaternion CCuaternion::operator + (const CCuaternion &q2) const { // at Ccuaternion.cpp
    return CCuaternion(w + q2.w, 
                       x + q2.x, 
                       y + q2.y, 
                       z + q2.z);
}
```

1. You were using `+=`
2. See the `const` modifier for `q2`

**Update**

In C++98, `const` means `logically constant`, the programmer promises the state of the argument will no be changed inside the function.

(Note: I changed the signature adding `const` at the end of the declaration so `this` can be constant too)

So, Why you need const?

1. It's a good practice: if the function is not going to change the value then it's just more polite to use const.
2. You may need it in another context, I mean, you must to be able to apply this operator not only on variables, but also on constants.

Comment: yeah I see my mistake now, but as I'm new to this, why it has to be const? does it make a difference that I didn't make it const?

Comment: thank you, I'll check later as I need to change some other overloads and functions in order to work with this changes.  :)

Answer (score 2):

The preferred way to overload addition operators is like this:

```
CCuaternion & CCuaternion::operator += (CCuaternion const &q2)
{
    w += q2.w;
    x += q2.x;
    y += q2.y;
    z += q2.z;

    return *this;
}
```

and this is a non-member function:

```
CCuaternion operator + (CCuaternion q1, CCuaternion const &q2)
{
    return q1 += q2;
}
```

This keeps your code very simple and intuitive and also lets people use `+=` on your class.